# Accessing (X, Y) coordinates in a one-dimensional double array with one element being X and the next being Y?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a one-dimensional double array that stores X and Y coordinates.

Element 0 would be the first X and element 1 would be the corresponding Y.

Element 2 would be the second X and so on.

Currently this is my code, but I was wondering if there is another way as this way is giving me some problems. The coordinates double array is already filled.

```
for(int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i+=2)
{
    double x = coordinates[i];
    double y = coordinates[i + 1]
}
```

My professor stated that he requires us to use a one-dimensional array for this assignment. If there is no other way, I can probably work around my problem and just go with the above approach, but I was just wondering if there is another way of doing this.

Using these coordinates I have to draw a polyline.
Here is my code used to draw the polyline.

```
Polyline shape = new Polyline();

for(double coord : coordinates)
{
    shape.getPoints().addAll(coord);
}
shape.setStrokeWidth(3);

return shape;
```

Here is an image of what is going on along with all the given coords.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBU9V.png

That extra line is bothering me.

-Edit: Thank you for everyone helping me. The problem was that my double array had a size of 500, and I was not using all of it, so most of the values were 0. I kept a track of how many coordinates I had and based my for loop condition on that rather than the length of the coordinate array.

Not exactly sure how to mark this as solved.

Comment: Is the coordinates array already filled?

Comment: Use a one dimensional array of `Point` objects, or a `List<Point>`.

Comment: @DaneBrick yes it is already filled.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I cannot use any class we have not learned. I have to use a double array.

Comment: Is the objective to access a certain point? Or all the points?

Comment: @DaneBrick I have to access all the points and draw a polyline (JavaFX) using the points. Problem is the polyline has an extra line going to the side. I have a feeling it's due to the code I have above.

Comment: the problem is that you can't access x and y outside the for loop, so if you are drawing the line, it must take place in the loop

Comment: Can you share the code how you are drawing the line ?

Comment: @SaifAsif Alright, I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String [] args){

    int[] coordinates = new int[10];
    int[] xArray = new int[10];
    int[] yArray = new int[10];

    for(int j = 0; j < coordinates.length; j++){
        coordinates[j] = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        System.out.println(coordinates[j]);
    }
    System.out.println();

    for(int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i+=2)
    {
        xArray[i] = coordinates[i];
        yArray[i] = coordinates[i + 1];
        System.out.println("x" + Integer.toString(i) + ": " + xArray[i]);
        System.out.println("y" + Integer.toString(i) + ": " + yArray[i]);
    }

}
```

I'm new so I dont know if i'll be any help, but the question was if there was any other way you could do it. This makes it so each coordinate is given a specific place in memory unlike in your for loop where it overrides x and y. I dont know how yours is filled so i just filled mine with random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0080__JavaFX_Polygon_Polyline.htm

it's amazing that method only need double array

so you don't need to use loop

```
    Polyline shape = new Polyline();
    shape.getPoints().addAll(coordinates);
    shape.setStrokeWidth(3);

    return shape;
```

also try to print your getPoints() value, it is any .clear method? maybe when you initialized the object, point(0,0) automatically added ad first

Comment: Thanks just changed my code. But it doesn't solve the problem. Might be some other part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the extra line there is coming from point (0, 0). I'm not very familiar with Java drawing tools, but it seems likely that (0, 0) is where the "pencil"'s position is initialized.

I've used Java drawing tools just a couple of times before, but I seem to remember there was some method you used to "lift the pencil" - otherwise, you would draw lines everywhere. Could that be what's causing the extra line? You would have to life the pencil, go to the first point, put down the pencil, and start drawing to fix the problem.